# Why pyspark count is so slow on a cached sample data?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using pyspark to do some data quality checks on very large data. (e.g, the `finaljoin` dataframe has shape of 90 million * 2310). Instead of running various filter function on the raw dataframe which takes a longer time, I created a subset data `finaljoin_test_percent0001` , which is a sample from `finaljoin` with 0.1% of number of rows. The subset data has been cached given the following code.

```
finaljoin = spark.read.csv('somewhere', header=True)
finaljoin_test_percent0001 = finaljoin.sample(0.001).cache()
```

However, the following code takes about 5 mins to get the shape of the data, which is (91932, 2310). I wonder if this is pretty common or if I misused cache in this way.

```
print((finaljoin_test_percent1.count(), len(finaljoin_test_percent1.columns)))


(2) Spark Jobs
  Job 55 View(Stages: 1/1)
    Stage 61: 12805/12805 
  Job 56 View(Stages: 1/1, 1 skipped)
(91932, 2310)
Command took 5.40 minutes
```

Comment: I think it is not yet cached but is cached when you trigger the count.

Comment: the first time any action is applied after mentioning the cache is when the actual caching of the data to memory happens. The next time you perform the count or any action, you will realize the performance gains.